# Is there a way of retrieving a TextView's visible line count or range?

Tags: android

I have a full-screen TextView holding a long Spanned that requires scrolling.  The TextView's getLineCount() gives me the total number of lines used for the entire block of text but I'd like to know how many lines of text are currently visible on the screen.

Or, better yet, is there a way to figure out the range of lines currently visible on the screen?  For example, as the view scrolls, can I tell that lines 20-60 are currently visible?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

```
int height    = myTextView.getHeight();
int scrollY   = myTextView.getScrollY();
Layout layout = myTextView.getLayout();

int firstVisibleLineNumber = layout.getLineForVertical(scrollY);
int lastVisibleLineNumber  = layout.getLineForVertical(scrollY+height);
```

Comment: @MrSuS it returns null if you want to retrieve it before View was laid out.

Comment: I tried using the above mentioned code but it returns wrong line count when using in the landscape orientation. Also few partial lines get visible.

Comment: for me to getting getLayout() returns null

Comment: getScrollY always returns 0 for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me returns the index of the last line (I checked by counting), maybe because of padding or something.

Answer (score 6):

To make them work you should write the code posted by @Robert in this way:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = txtViewEx.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ViewTreeObserver obs = txtViewEx.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                height = txtViewEx.getHeight();
                scrollY = txtViewEx.getScrollY();
                Layout layout = txtViewEx.getLayout();

                firstVisibleLineNumber = layout.getLineForVertical(scrollY);
                lastVisibleLineNumber = layout.getLineForVertical(height+scrollY);

            }
        });
```