# How to get number of lines of TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I want to get the number of lines of a text view

```
textView.setText("Test line 1 Test line 2 Test line 3 Test line 4 Test line 5.............")
```

`textView.getLineCount();` always returns **zero**

Then I have also tried:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = this.textView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        ViewTreeObserver obs = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
        obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        System.out.println(": " + textView.getLineCount());

    }
});
```

It returns the exact output.

But this works only for a static layout.

When I am inflating the layout dynamically this doesn't work anymore.

How could I find the number of line in a TextView?

Comment: yes i know, i have already mentioned that not i face this problem while inflating layout dynamically.

Comment: I think [this is helpful for you.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239356/is-there-a-way-of-retrieving-a-textviews-visible-line-count-or-range

Comment: @hardikjoshi:thax already tried this, but didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way of retrieving a TextView's visible line count or range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239356/is-there-a-way-of-retrieving-a-textviews-visible-line-count-or-range)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679147/how-to-get-line-count-of-textview-before-rendering/28525249.

Answer (score 116):

I was able to get `getLineCount()` to not return 0 using a `post`, like this:

```
textview.setText(“Some text”);
textview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int lineCount = textview.getLineCount();
        // Use lineCount here
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you give more details about your code that was trying to get the line count of a `TextView`? Maybe there's some detail in the adapter that may be causing the views to be loaded differently than the expected?

Comment: I solved it by different approach and now its working fine I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22217849/2579281

Comment: Thanks for sharing what worked for your `RecycleView`. That's an interesting approach and definitely worth a try if this simpler code didn't do the trick for that specific case. :)

Answer (score 42):

As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528790/textview-getlinecount-always-0-in-android),

> `getLineCount()` will give you the correct number of lines only after
>   a layout pass.

It means that you need to render the `TextView` first before invoking the `getLineCount()` method.

Comment: thax for ans but still have problem

Comment: this is correct. You must not be adding the listener correctly. Add the OnGlobalLayoutListener directly to the TextView instance and not the parent layout.

Comment: This only works if textview contains line breaks, but it doesn't work for word wrap

Answer (score 33):

`ViewTreeObserver` is not so reliable especially when using dynamic layouts such as `ListView`.

Let's assume:
1. You will do some work depending on the lines of `TextView`.
2. The work is not very urgent and can be done later.

Here is my solution:

```
public class LayoutedTextView extends TextView {

        public LayoutedTextView(Context context) {
                super(context);
        }

        public LayoutedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
        }

        public LayoutedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public interface OnLayoutListener {
                void onLayouted(TextView view);
        }

        private OnLayoutListener mOnLayoutListener;

        public void setOnLayoutListener(OnLayoutListener listener) {
                mOnLayoutListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
                        int bottom) {
                super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

                if (mOnLayoutListener != null) {
                        mOnLayoutListener.onLayouted(this);
                }
        }

}
```

Usage:

```
LayoutedTextView tv = new LayoutedTextView(context);
tv.setOnLayoutListener(new OnLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayouted(TextView view) {
                int lineCount = view.getLineCount();
                // do your work
        }
});
```

Comment: Neat approach. I employed this approach in a listview. Works like a charm.

Comment: I tried other approach but only this solution is working perfect. I tested it in recycleview.

Comment: not call listener any help appreciate check my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790803/using-viewtreeobserver-i-am-adding-setmaxlines-and-setellipsize-in-materialtextv

Comment: @VikashKumarVerma Can u please share how it works for u in recyclerView, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 24):

```
 textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            // Remove listener because we don't want this called before _every_ frame
            textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this)

            // Drawing happens after layout so we can assume getLineCount() returns the correct value
            if(textView.getLineCount() > 2) {
                // Do whatever you want in case text view has more than 2 lines
            }  

            return true; // true because we don't want to skip this frame
        }
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this didn't get more vote. This needs to the selected answer. Using a layout listener will provide callback once the layout is complete, which means that any changes that are needs in the purview of the parent are not possible. Example: a scroll view having children. How does one make all the children adjust depending on something happening in one of the children. Thus, OnPreDraw works better and more efficiently.

Comment: inside this method getting infinite number of calls

Comment: using RecyclerView.Adapter call every time and hang phone @priti

Answer (score 10):

I think the crux of this question is that people want to be able to find out the size of a TextView in advance so that they can dynamically resize it to nicely fit the text. A typical use might be to create talk bubbles (at least that was what I was working on).

I tried several solutions, including use of getTextBounds() and measureText() as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549182/android-paint-measuretext-vs-gettextbounds). Unfortunately, both methods are slightly inexact and have no way to account for line breaks and unused linespace. So, I gave up on that approach.

That leaves getLineCount(), whose problem is that you have to "render" the text before getLineCount() will give you the number of lines, which makes it a chicken-and-egg situation. I read various solutions involving listeners and layouts, but just couldn't believe that there wasn't something simpler.

After fiddling for two days, I finally found what I was looking for (at least it works for me). It all comes down to what it means to "render" the text. It doesn't mean that the text has to appear onscreen, only that it has to be prepared for display internally. This happens whenever a call is made directly to invalidate() or indirectly as when you do a setText() on your TextView, which calls invalidate() for you since the view has changed appearance.

Anyway, here's the key code (assume you already know the talk bubble's lineWidth and lineHeight of a single line based on the font):

```
TextView talkBubble;
// No peeking while we set the bubble up.
talkBubble.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
// I use FrameLayouts so my talk bubbles can overlap
// lineHeight is just a filler at this point
talkBubble.setLayoutParams( new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( lineWidth, lineHeight ) );
// setText() calls invalidate(), which makes getLineCount() do the right thing.
talkBubble.setText( "This is the string we want to dynamically deal with." );
int lineCount = getLineCount();
// Now we set the real size of the talkBubble.
talkBubble.setLayoutParams( new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( lineWidth, lineCount * lineHeight ) );
talkBubble.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
```

Anyway, that's it. The next redraw will give a bubble tailor-made for your text.

Note: In the actual program, I use a separate bubble for determining lines of text so that I can resize my real bubble dynamically both in terms of length and width. This allows me to shrink my bubbles left-to-right for short statements, etc.

Enjoy!

Comment: I'd guess that this works for you because you are using a fixed line width in code, or a pre-calculated one. For wrap content or match parent, this doesn't work, though, as those values also still have to be calculated.

Answer (score 10):

You could also use `PrecomputedTextCompat` for getting the number of lines. 
Regular method:

```
fun getTextLineCount(textView: TextView, text: String, lineCount: (Int) -> (Unit)) {
    val params: PrecomputedTextCompat.Params = TextViewCompat.getTextMetricsParams(textView)
    val ref: WeakReference<TextView>? = WeakReference(textView)

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val text = PrecomputedTextCompat.create(text, params)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            ref?.get()?.let { textView ->
                TextViewCompat.setPrecomputedText(textView, text)
                lineCount.invoke(textView.lineCount)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call this method:

```
getTextLineCount(textView, "Test line 1 Test line 2 Test line 3 Test line 4 Test line 5.............") { lineCount ->
     //count of lines is stored in lineCount variable
}
```

Or maybe you can create extension method for it like this:

```
fun TextView.getTextLineCount(text: String, lineCount: (Int) -> (Unit)) {
    val params: PrecomputedTextCompat.Params = TextViewCompat.getTextMetricsParams(this)
    val ref: WeakReference<TextView>? = WeakReference(this)

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val text = PrecomputedTextCompat.create(text, params)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            ref?.get()?.let { textView ->
                TextViewCompat.setPrecomputedText(textView, text)
                lineCount.invoke(textView.lineCount)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then you call it like this:

```
textView.getTextLineCount("Test line 1 Test line 2 Test line 3 Test line 4 Test line 5.............") { lineCount ->
     //count of lines is stored in lineCount variable
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on [@secnelis idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037377/how-to-get-number-of-lines-of-textview/22217849#22217849), there is even a more clean way if you target API 11 or higher.

Instead of extending a `TextView` you can use already built-in functionality if `View.OnLayoutChangeListener`

In `ListAdapter.getView()`, for instance

```
if (h.mTitle.getLineCount() == 0 && h.mTitle.getText().length() != 0) {
    h.mTitle.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(final View v, final int left, final int top,
                final int right, final int bottom, final int oldLeft,
                final int oldTop, final int oldRight, final int oldBottom) {
            h.mTitle.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            final int count = h.mTitle.getLineCount();
            // do stuff
        }
    });
} else {
    final int count = h.mTitle.getLineCount();
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also calculate the amount of lines through this function:

```
private fun countLines(textView: TextView): Int {
        return Math.ceil(textView.paint.measureText(textView.text.toString()) /
                textView.measuredWidth.toDouble()).toInt()
    }
```

Keep in mind that It may not work very well on a `RecyclerView` though.

Answer (score 1):

```
textview.getText().toString().split(System.getProperty("line.separator")).length
```

It works fine for me to get number of lines of TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this `onCreate`? The Views aren't laid out yet, so `getLineCount()` is 0 for a while. If you do this later in the Window LifeCycle, you'll get your line count. You'll have a hard time doing it `onCreate`, but `onWindowFocusChanged` with `hasFocus=true` usually has the Views measured by now.

The `textView.post()` suggestion is also a good one

Answer (score 0):

I have used the textView.lineCount method as well. I have a project where I want to show a maximum of 4 lines, then I identify whether or not I need to show a read more text if the actual text that goes into the text view needs more than 4 lines. It worked fine most of the time, but on some edge cases, the lineCount method returned 1 more then the actual visible lines (5 instead of 4). This resulted in Read More label getting presented but in reality, no more text to be read when it is clicked.
(And I was waiting until the layout is rendered to check the line count)

After researching for some time, I found out that there is actually a method that works more reliably for my use case. I wanted to share if it helps anyone.

```
                   val maxTextLines = 4
                   textView.text = "Some string that may or may not exceed 4 lines"
                    val width = if (textView.lineCount >= (maxTextLines + 1)) {
                        textView.layout.getLineWidth(maxTextLines)
                    } else {
                        0f
                    }
                    if (width != 0f) {
                        readMoreView.visibility = VISIBLE
                        textView.maxLines = maxTextLines
                        readMoreView.setOnClickListener {
                            if (textView.maxLines == maxTextLines) {
                                textView.maxLines = Integer.MAX_VALUE
                                readMoreView.text = context.getString(R.string.read_less)
                            } else {
                                textView.maxLines = maxTextLines
                                readMoreView.text = context.getString(R.string.read_more)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        readMoreView.visibility = GONE
                    }
```

I know the code above is not an exact response to this question but this logic of line width can be used in conjunction with the lineCount method to make sure it does not return an additional incorrect line which is essentially empty.