# Detect if TextView spans over 2 lines

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I wonder if there are any ways to detect either if string to be fitted into a text view reaches the end of screen and therefore change line, or if a textview spans over 2 lines?

I want to know this so I can increase margins between some textviews if a textview spans over 2 lines, of course I want to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`TextView` supports `getLineCount()` - See [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineCount%28%29) careful as you may need to check if the view has been drawn first.

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm, as long as it's being used after the layout has been drawn.

Comment: As a side note since I discarded this answer at first: you may need to call `textView.onPreDraw()` if you just changed the view contents; otherwise the value returned by `getLineCount()` will be 0

Comment: if `result 0` then try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32340660/9868485