# Checking Text in TextView is on a single line

Tags: android, textview

How do I detect whether the text in a `TextView` is on one line or not.

if it extends past one line, i want to use `128dp` `Toolbar`

if its on a single line, i want to use `48dp`

Comment: android:lines                   = "1"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if TextView spans over 2 lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444060/detect-if-textview-spans-over-2-lines)  - `TextView.getLineCount()`

Comment: @Doomsknight, always returning 0 (((

Comment: @AskQuestion it means internal Layout has not been built yet

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `android:singleLine` attribute to `true`.

Refer to [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: I dont want to use a singleLine attribute. Read please again that I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

if it return 1 then the text is single line as below

```
int lineCount=mTextView.getLineCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(yourTv.getLineCount() > 1) {
    yourTv.setTextSize();
else {
    yourTv.setTextSize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StaticLayout

```
    TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
    textPaint.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface());
    textPaint.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize());
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.ALIGN_NORMAL);
    StaticLayout staticLayout = new StaticLayout(textString, textPaint, widthTextView, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1f, 0f, true);
    if (1 == staticLayout.getLineCount()) {
        //do smth
    } else {
        //do smth else
    }
```