# Android - Move textView if it doesn't fit

Tags: android, textview, width

I have 3 TextViews inside a linearLayout (horizontal), and when the last textview is too big or there is no space for it, it is matching parent and looking like the image below:

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTZa1.png)

What I want is to, IF the textview reaches the linearlayout's width, then, the textview should be moved below "Property" textView. (next line)

Take a look at how it should be:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfX4e.png)

That's a snippet of my XML:

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                    android:text="Property"
                    android:id="@+id/txtPropertyType" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                    android:text="/ 127 m"
                    android:id="@+id/txtArea"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                    android:text="/ 3 roomsssssssssdddd"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:id="@+id/txtNumRoom"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your xml and add another TextView below the LinearLayout:

```
        <LinearLayout

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                android:text="Property"
                android:id="@+id/txtPropertyType" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                android:text="/ 127 m"
                android:id="@+id/txtArea"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                android:text="/ 3 roomsssssssssdddd"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:id="@+id/txtNumRoom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:id="@+id/long_room"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfgdfdfgddfgdfgdd"/>
```

Now, you have 2 options:

**OPTION 1:** Check the length of the room number textview. If it's more than, say, 12 (you have to find the number considering all letters to be widest ones - like `w`), then make the visibility of `txtNumRoom` GONE and that of `long_room` visible.

**OPTION 2:** Find the height of the `txtNumRoom` before it gets rendered and displayed. If this height is greater than height of `txtArea`, that means the textview has gone multiple-lines. Again, in that case,make the visibility of `txtNumRoom` GONE and that of `long_room` visible.
Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908003/getting-height-of-text-view-before-rendering-to-layout) to know how to find height of a textview programmatically before it gets rendered.

Comment: it worked! I needed to  do an adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in my listView, but it worked :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:singleLine="true" on each text view. Your problem here is that your TextView is spreading on more than one line.

Comment: if I set singleLine as true, it will always ellipsize when it does not fit.. and I dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

Since August 2020, there is the option to use a `ConstraintLayout` with the virtual layout `Flow`.

Your elements should be wrapped in a `ConstraintLayout` together with a `Flow` element like in the following sample XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:text="Property"
        android:id="@+id/txtPropertyType"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:text="/ 127 m"
        android:id="@+id/txtArea"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:text="/ 3 roomssssssssssssssssssssss"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:id="@+id/txtNumRoom"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/flow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="txtPropertyType, txtArea, txtNumRoom"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="4dp"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_horizontalBias="0.0"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/flow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:text="$2000.000"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The elements that are involved in the wrapping (all elements in the line that must wrap if too big) must have ids which are then added in the `app:constraint_referenced_ids` tag of `Flow`.

`app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"` and `app:flow_horizontalBias="0.0"` are necessary to left-align your text (`flow_horizontalBias` won't work unless elements are packed), but can be changed depending on the layout you want to achieve.

`app:flow_wrapMode` tells the flow-layout how to position elements, and must be set to either `chain` or `aligned`, once again `chain` was necessary to be able to left-align the text.

It is also important to set the height of the `Flow` element to `0dp` so it can determine how much space it needs by itself.

The `TextView` below should be constrained to the `Flow` element so that it can be positioned dynamically depending on the position of the elements inside.

[Screenshot of the layout with small text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enUWm.png)

[Screenshot of the layout with overflowing text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pat5v.png)