# TextView won't update height to wrap_content programmatically

Tags: android, textview

I want for the `TextView` height to be `wrap_content`, and then add an extra space, say `8dp`. I tried this:

```
textView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
textView.setText("Hello world!");
textView.requestLayout();

textView.setHeight(textView.getHeight() + Math.round(convertDpToPx(8)));
```

but the height is being set to `8dp` instead of `WRAP_CONENT + 8dp`

Comment: Leave the height to wrap_content and add padding of 8dp. If you want the padding only vertical use paddingTop and paddingBottom. And do it preferably in the layout

Comment: @jeprubio it won't work in my case, I'm using a ```SpannableString``` with custom ```ReplacementSpan``` to make a rounded corner highlighting. if the ```TextView``` height is not big enough, it will cause the highlighting to be cut off from the bottom. padding didn't solve it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably the height of your text returns 0, because You are trying to get it's height before it has drawn. So you need to use addOnGlobalLayoutListener to get the height of view after it has drawn. Like this,

```
textView.setText("Hello world!");
    textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height =textView.getHeight() + Math.round(convertDpToPx(8);
            textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually thought ```requestLayout()``` would force the ```TextView``` to redraw itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to add a space around the text, consider using paddings or margins.
2. Instead of "getHeight", try "getMeasuredHeight".
3. If you really wanna know the height of your text, there is another way to evaluate that. See [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908003/getting-height-of-text-view-before-rendering-to-layout).