# How can i split long text to fit in Textview Android

Tags: android, string, android-studio, android-layout, textview

For example, I have a very long text and I have a text view at the center of the screen with the below properties.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conftextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:minHeight="350dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Now, I created an OnClick Listener so that for each tap the text changes and starts from where it ended last.

I have few constraints here the text view can be either **square** or **height < width** but not **height > width**. So, I figured that having exactly 22 lines per view solves my problem.

But, how can I split the content into exactly 22 lines I tried to do with word split and considering 200 words per view but if there are many lines breaks this logic is failing.

```
    /*
    Process and split text into 200 worded parts
     */
    protected TreeMap<Integer,String> processText(String inputText, int maxWords){
        TreeMap<Integer,String> multiPageText= new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
        String words[] = inputText.split(" ");
        int wordCount = words.length;
        int keyCount = (int) Math.ceil(wordCount/(double)maxWords);


        for (int i = 0; i < keyCount;i++){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j=i*maxWords;j<((i+1)*maxWords < wordCount ? (i+1)*maxWords : wordCount);j++){
                sb.append(words[j]);
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            multiPageText.put(i, sb.toString().trim());
        }

//        System.out.println(keyCount);
        return multiPageText;
    }
```

Using the Map returned above I am handling different pages but I am looking for a way where I can split the text exactly at 22 lines regardless of how many line breaks were there or how long the text is.

Any leads would be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could put this as a comment, but there's a really great answer here that goes into detail about what you're looking for [Getting height of text view before rendering to layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908003/getting-height-of-text-view-before-rendering-to-layout)