# Set some text bold in textview, but not everything

Tags: android, textview, bold, font-style

Is there any possibility to set some text **bold**. For example:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorLink="#004c93"
            android:text="Hello everyone, I am Max!"/>
```

***"Hello everyone,"*** should have a normal `font-style`, but ***"I am Max!"*** should be bold.
Is there anyway like in **html** I can use `<strong></strong>`?

I have a text with about 400 rows and the text is located in the **values directory** and more precisely in the `strings.xml`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Android docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan

```
 SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Bold and italic text");
 string.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 string.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 9, 15, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Then call `textView.setText(string);` like you normally would.

EDIT: You can also try using
`HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);`
which also returns a `Spanned` of its own.

However, if you're putting this html as a string resource, you will need to escape some XML characters.

Comment: Is there a chance to use "lines" instead of "symbols" ?

Comment: I assume you mean formatting by line as opposed to formatting per word/character? 
If so, I doubt there's an easy, out-of-the-box solution. Since `TextView` itself decides how many lines the string will be rendered into. You might have to implement a workaround yourself. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679147/how-to-get-line-count-of-textview-before-rendering

Comment: Otherwise, a less robust solution would be inserting the line breaks yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `Html` class which help us use Html text in android `view`

Just like this

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hello everyone, <strong>I am Max!</strong>"));
```

this will look like this

Hello everyone, **I am Max!**

Comment: Ty for your answer but my text has about 400 lines and I get it from a string.xml file