# How to count number of characters from fixed height and width Textview in android?

Tags: android, textview

I am working on display my story text in a custom book page.When a story text is reached the maximum limit of characters then remaining text are not be able to display.
I am logically working on to get numbers of character in a fixed size TextView in android.

```
How can i get number of characters when Textview has fixed text size, width and height?
```

Suggestions are most welcome...

Thanks is advance

Comment: @MukeshKushwaha please refer this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/32340660/3946958  And let me know in case of concern