# Make TextView automatically delete old text?

Tags: android, textview

I am using a TextView for log purposes inside an Android app, and if it gets too long the app becomes unstable. Is it possible to set a max limit so TextView removes old text after it gets to a certain size? If not I can set the app to automatically clear the text once a day. If I want to clear the text manually, do I call `TextView.clearComposingText();` ?

Comment: Don't you think using a file for logs will be a better idea ?

Comment: no, because I want to be able to see the logs conveniently. The logs are for short term only.

Comment: How about combininig maxLines and answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037377/how-to-get-number-of-lines-of-textview

Comment: Save your log's inside a file and when needed show the some part of the file inside a textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="100"/>
```

Set the maximum length of the textview to a limit number and also check when to clear the textview.
Write the following function in Activity and call it on onCreate.

```
private void checklength(){
   if(textview.getText().length()==100){
       textview.setText("");
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.