# How to show read more text if text has more than 4 maxlines?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to show read more or continue reading if text has more than 4 lines. how to do that, I tried some way it doesn't work;

```
 if (myHolder.userTexts.getMaxLines()==4){
        myHolder.showMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        myHolder.showMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

And if you want to look at my layout;

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showMore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/conti_read"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: I think  you should use this to get the number of lines in your textview `textView.getLineCount()`

Comment: can you please write full code. should i use if else staement?

Comment: replace `myHolder.userTexts.getMaxLines()==4` with this `myHolder.userTexts.getLineCount()>=4`

Comment: i tired but does not work

Comment: where did you put your if statement? your logic is correct try debugging your code and check your program flow

Comment: i put in my adapter

Comment: in onBindViewHolder

Comment: If you are trying to get it on `Adapter` this would be the best approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252000/3111083

Comment: can you show me you whole adapter code.

Comment: sorry i can''t see whole code because there are so many code

Comment: Thanks bro:) the link you shared works! Thanks :) I was looking for this again thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
if (text.length() > length) {
            String sub = text.substring(0, length);

            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sub + "<font color='#F39322'> " + seeMore + "</font>"));


            textView.setOnClickListener(view -> {

                if (textView.getText().equals(text)) {
                    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sub + "<font color='#F39322'> " + seeMore + "</font>"));
                } else {
                    textView.setText(text);

                }
            });

        } else {
            textView.setText(text);

        }
```

please vote me if this was useful for you