# How to determine the number of lines visible in TextView?

Tags: android, textview, lines

how to get how many lines are displayed in visible part of `TextView`? I use text, which not fully placed in `TextView` on every screen resolution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logs_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

String s = "very big text"
TextView logText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.logs_text);
logText.setText(s);
```

Comment: do you want to set how many lines the textview will have, or just get how many lines does he have?

Comment: rephrased the question

Comment: use textviewobject.getText() to get the text set on textview and compare with original text.

Comment: I someone is googling it to just limit number of lines in TextView then it's enough to set *maxLines* and *ellipsize* properties of the TextView: for example `android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way of retrieving a TextView's visible line count or range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239356/is-there-a-way-of-retrieving-a-textviews-visible-line-count-or-range)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[android.text.Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html) contains this information and more. Use `textView.getLayout().getLineCount()` to obtain line count.

Be wary that `getLayout()` might return `null` if called before the layout process finishes. Call `getLayout()` after `onGlobalLayout()` or `onPreDraw()` of `ViewTreeObserver`. E.g.

```
textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(() -> {
    final int lineCount = textView.getLayout().getLineCount();
});
```

If you want only visible line count you should probably use the approach mentioned in the answer below:

[Is there a way of retrieving a TextView's visible line count or range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239356/is-there-a-way-of-retrieving-a-textviews-visible-line-count-or-range)

Comment: I see 25 lines in textview, but when I use getLineCount(), I get 152 in logcat

Comment: It returns number of lines in the layout, not the number of visible lines in layout. Anyway, you can count them using Layout. Gonna update the answer soon.

Comment: Try this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239356/is-there-a-way-of-retrieving-a-textviews-visible-line-count-or-range

Comment: Get real line count: `int count = editView.getText().toString().split("\\r?\\n").length;`

Comment: textView.getLayout() is returning null

Comment: @Neeraj thanks for letting me now. Now I see it might return null before layout process is finished. I've updated the answer to reflect this problem.