# Is it possible to know the number of visible words? not full length?

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to know the number of visible words? not full length?

I add to textView string from 100 words. But visible only 10 words. How do I know that only 10 words?

```
Log.e("asdas", String.valueOf(messageView.length()));
```

not working

Sorry if this question is too complex :((

Comment: i don't think so you can achieve this

Comment: XY problem. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I also understood. Since length is the length of the full

Comment: I want to continue the text http://snag.gy/WVrkN.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "visible"? What makes text "invisible"?

Comment: :). set to textView max lines 2. add text from 1000 words and you will see what I mean

Comment: As a starting point use `Paint.measureText` method. It should suffice all your needs.

Comment: not)). for ellipsis  there is an attribute ellipsize in TextView.   this is not

Comment: Well. ask the question a different way)). How to split the text between the 2?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8798989/4428462) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2239356/4428462)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know WHY you need this, but here it goes:

```
int start = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(0);
int end = textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(textView.getLineCount() - 1);
String displayed = textView.getText().toString().substring(start, end);
int visibleWords = displayed.split(" ").length
```

Comment: Not!
        int start = messageView.getLayout().getLineStart(1);

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.Poetry.PageAuthors.SetAuthorText(PageAuthors.java:116)

This is not working.

Comment: Did you understand the code? Or simply put it into your code and expected to work? Did getLayout() return anything different from null?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody interested and getting the NullPointerException, here's a working example of Christian's answer:

```
    ViewTreeObserver vto = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int start = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(0);
                int end = textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(textView.getLineCount() - 1);
                String displayed = textView.getText().toString().substring(start, end);
                int visibleWords = displayed.split(" ").length;
            }
        });
```